# Reference for compact embedding for Holder space on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, interpolation-theory

Suppose $0<\alpha<\beta$, and $\Omega$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the Holder space $C^{\beta}(\Omega)$ is **compactly embedded** into $C^{\alpha}(\Omega)$. But if $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$, then the compact embedding  is not true.

However, if we consider the weaker weighted Holder space $C^{\alpha, -\delta}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (for any $\delta>0$) instead of  $C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then is  $C^{\beta}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ compactly embedded to $C^{\alpha, -\delta}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Here
$$
\|f\|_{C^{\alpha, -\delta}}=\|(1+|\cdot|^2)^{-\frac{\delta}{2}}f\|_{C^{\alpha}}.
$$

I could not find a precise reference from some books on functional analysis. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A few years late, but the question had been cross-posted to and answered on MathOverflow apparently: https://mathoverflow.net/q/321224

Comment: @BrunoB. Many thanks!